# User management with Firebase in SwiftUI where to start?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, swiftui

I'm trying to understand back end development with Firebase in SwiftUI, I have developed a small application in which we can actually login with Firebase Auth. I would like to display a pop-up when the user logs in for the first time, Firebase doesn't have a function already done for that so I would like to code one but where to start?

I wanted to get the UID of the user when he logs in and put it in the "user_data" database if it wasn't already there otherwise ignore the rest of my function. If it is not there then display a pop-up in which he can choose a flag that will be assigned to him (for example a city) and then display the restaurants in his city for example.

The question may seem silly but I am new to this field and I would like to improve because it interests me a lot and seeks to understand and document me as much as possible on the back end of swiftUI.

Thank you for your precious help and advice.

Comment: The question is pretty vague so we need you to clarify it. *I would like to display a pop-up*; you're the programmer, so you should add code to display whatever popup you want. If you want to get the uid of the user and store it, then you need to write that code. There are lot of examples of how to write data in the Firebase guide - however, we don't know which Firebase product you're using so I can't link the specific documentation. Can you include the code you've attempted? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (result, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    if result?.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser == true{
                       //is a new user
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @DanyT777 I am not sure this answers the question. The [signIn](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#sign_in_existing_users) function is for existing users *that have already been created*. e.g. when a user first uses the app, [createUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#sign_up_new_users) is called that creates the account, generates a uid and signs them in the first time - that's when you capture their newly created uid and show them a popup. If you're using signIn, that process has already happened.

Comment: Also, [isNewUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AdditionalUserInfo#isnewuser) will return false since createUser authenticated the user  when the user was created. More info in the Firebase Guide [create account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account)