# First time SignIn pop-up with Firebase SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, swiftui

I'm trying to make a feature to show a pop-up when a user logs in for the first time with Firebase, except that when I print it doesn't work. When printing it returns false in all cases

Good to know, the accounts are created from the console!

AuthView.swift

```
    func on_connect() {
        if self.email != "" && self.pass != "" {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.email, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in
                if err != nil {
                    self.error = err!.localizedDescription
                    self.alert.toggle()
                    return
                }
            
                if res?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser == true{
                    print("IM NEW!")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
                }
                else{
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil)
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Thanks for your precious help!

Comment: You asked the same question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66747036/user-management-with-firebase-in-swiftui-where-to-start) You should replace `self.first_log = true` with the code that pops up a window. And... there are bigger issues; The `signIn` function is for **existing users that have already been created** e.g. when a user first uses the app, `createUser` is called that creates the account, generates a uid and signs them in the first time; that's when you capture their new uid and show them a popup. If you're using signIn, that process has already happened*.

Comment: *if you are creating users in Firebase Console, then signin will be the correct place to capture that info. If however, you are allowing users to create the own account with `createUser`, that's not going to work.

Comment: Hello Jay, I think you will have understood by the wording of my questions all this is unclear to me, I tried several things without success so my last post was a bit desperate. Thank you for your reasoning and attention, I do create accounts with the Firebase console, I will try to replace what you told me because that means it should work. Otherwise I will try to find out more about the doc and the methods available to me. I apologize for the inconclusive questions and thank you very much for your patience!

Comment: @Jay I added  `guard let newUser = res?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser else {return}
 print("\nIs new user? \n(newUser)\n") `
in the function that is called when the user clicks on "connect" in `Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.email, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in`
but it constantly returns false. I created the user via the Firebase console just now

Comment: Please do not put code in comments, they are very hard to read. Add the code to the *question* and ensure it's properly formatted for readability. Update the question and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue #1**:

You have two `delivViewModel`s:

```
@ObservedObject private var viewModel = delivViewModel()
@ObservedObject var first_log: delivViewModel
```

The first one is getting created inside `LoggedView` and the second looks like it's getting passed in via a parameter. It's hard to imagine a scenario where you'd need both, so get rid of one of them so that you don't end up calling functions on both, which happens later on:

```
self.viewModel.is_first_loggin() // called on viewModel
print("first sign in-> \($first_log.first_log)")  // called on first_log
```

**Issue #2**:

`Auth.auth().signIn`, like nearly every network function, is *asynchronous*. This means that it doesn't return immediately (it'll return at an indeterminate point in the future), so code run directly after it will complete *before* `signIn` itself has completed. However, the code in the *callback function/closure* (what you see in the `{}` after `signIn`) will get called after its completion.

In terms of printing the value, I'd just move that code inside of the callback function. You'd have:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (result, error) in
             if error == nil {
                 if result?.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser == true {
                    self.first_log = true
                 } else {
                    self.first_log = false
                 }
                 print("First log in? \(self.first_log)")
             }
         }
```

In terms of showing the popup that you mentioned, you can show that conditionally based on `$viewModel.first_log` (this is assuming that you've chosen `viewModel` to be the `delivViewModel` you want to keep.

Something like:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.first_log) {
  Text("Popup stuff")
}
```

If you did want a way to respond to `first_log` in your view once it is asynchronously set, you could also look into `onReceive` ([How can I get data from ObservedObject with onReceive in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103186/how-can-i-get-data-from-observedobject-with-onreceive-in-swiftui)), however there may not be a use case for it here (unless you're going to drop back into UIKit to display the popup imperatively or something).

Comment: I followed your advice but unfortunately it still doesn't work, my pop-up is displayed all the time even if it's the 2nd time the user logs in, maybe this can come from my function? In fact my function doesn't print anything so I'm a bit lost

Comment: You'd have to show me the code for me to diagnose what is going on.

Comment: Pretty good answer but this `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not needed inside Firebase closures. UI calls are alway done on the main thread and networking is done on a background thread.